# Ajax loading images in XML - loading image and fade?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, getelementbyid

I am loading in an XML document with multiple photos in it, via ajax.
The process my function goes through is this:

Open a UL
Open a LI
Open an img tag
set the src to = the url in the xml document (see below)
close img tag
close LI
open a LI
open an img tag
set the src to = the url in the xml document (see below)
close img tag
close LI
close UL

It creates a new List item and puts the img tag inside for each individual tag in the xml document.
And the xml is this, but with more entries:

```
<images><image><url>0.jpg</url></image><image><url>1.jpg</url></image></images>
```

and a snippit of my function that deals with the image src is

```
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + "<li>";
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("url");
        {
        try
          {txt=txt + "<img class='fade' src='" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "' />";
    }
        catch (er)
          {txt=txt + "<li class='fade'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /></li>";}
        }
  txt=txt + "</li>";
      }
```

My question is, how do I make these fade in once they have been loaded? and how should i go about adding the loading.gif's behind? I was thinking of a simliar function that writes image tags with loading.gif as the src, then in the function above getting each element by id and changing the src. gonna give this a go, any other soltions welcome. But mainly i need to work out howo to fade this bad boy.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the images with:

```
 style="display:none;"
```

And then when your function finishes adding the images call jquery fade:

```
 $('img').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

As aviv says, you should set the `display: none` at first, because `.fadeIn` animates the opacity of image from it's current state to 100%.

And what about loading.gif.

there are many ways you can go, for example at firts you can set the `src` of each image to `loading.gif`, and then, after ajax request, you will change the `src` to your image. in this case you should set `display: none` before changing each src.

Or you can have other img elements(as loadings) with position absolute for example. In this case you should change their style to `display: none` after ajax request.

happy coding;)

Answer (score 0):

---

```
   *Upate*
```

---

Hi, thanks for the answers but I am still racking my brain over this problem.
basically i can get each part to work seperatly, but not all together.

The problem I cannot get my head around is this:
To be able to fade the image ontop of the loading.gif, the gif needs to be a bg image.
To load the images, an ajax request is needed and images are only loaded on the page once they have successfully loaded via ajax.
I need the loading.gif's to load with the page, which means I have to set up a blank structure of 100 LI's on the page.
I can then use `.html()` to insert the `<img src=[url from xml file] />` into the LI.. yes?
But the problem I am having is that the page freezes while it is doing this and it loads all the images at once as opposed to one at a time.

So I thought, create a function that each img can run onload, which starts the ajax script to get the next image to load.
I don't think this is great. And I am having a problem writing the function.
Theory of it goes:

image0 loads and fades in,
image0 completes loading and activates `loadNext()`
In `loadnext()` : 
the id is increased, (which is an attr in the xml starting 0 to 100)
get the url (which is an element in xml) relevant to the new id
add to the unordered list, and run `loadNext()` on image1 onload.

I cant get it to work though :(
help please

Answer (score 0):

Patches will not work on **drupal**, however cdn module works with **pressflow**.

Try this:

```
themname_template_preprocess_page(){
    //regular expression for CDN call
}
```